# How to make IntelliJ indent wrapped condition in JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, indentation

When I have JavaScript-Code like this:

```
if(conditionOne &&
   conditionTwo) {
   doSomething();
}
```

JSLint complains

> Expected 'conditionTwo' at column {n+4}, not column {n}.

Where n is the column where `conditionOne` and `conditionTwo` begin.

(How) can I configure IntelliJ to format my code this way instead?

```
if(conditionOne &&
       conditionTwo) {
   doSomething();
}
```

I did look in Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript but did not find such an option (or did not recognize it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the "Continuation Indent" under Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript

I set mine to 8 and it formats your block correctly.

Under the "Tabs and Indents" tab, I unchecked "Use tab character", Tab size is 4, Indent is 4, and Continuation indent is 8. Then it formats it according to your example.

Comment: Sorry, that does not seem to do what I want. conditionOne and conditionTwo still start at the same column with continuation-indent set to 8 (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: What product are you using? WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA? What version?

In IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5, Ctrl+Alt+L (reformat hotkey) formats your first code sample to exactly match the second code sample.

Comment: IntelliJ 12.1.14, my bad, I changed the default settings without changing the project settings.